# this.state return empty array when render

Tags: react-native

I wanted to display the array `series` and when I tried to console the array `this.state.series` in the function it does has the result and the value inside but when I render `this.state.series` just keep giving empty array. I wonder is it because of the `componentDidMount()`?

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={series:[]}
      }

    GetTransaction=()=> {
       
        var APIURL="http://10.0.2.2:80/api/getTransaction.php";

        var headers={
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application.json'
        }


        fetch(APIURL,
            {
                method:'POST',
                headers: headers,
                
            })
        .then((response)=>response.json()) 
        .then((response)=>
        {
            
            this.setState({results:response});
            
             this.state.results[0].map((a) => {
                
            this.state.series.push(a.count)
            });
            
            console.log(this.state.series)
        })   
        .catch((error)=>
        {
            alert("Error"+error);
        }
        ) 
       
       
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){ // runs after the component output has been rendered to the DOM
        this.GetTransaction();
    }
    

    render(){
          
        console.log(this.state.series)
```

output

```
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array [
  "1",
  "2",
  "1",
  "1",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically 2 errors in `GetTransaction` state assignment:

1. you can't read a state just assigned because `this.setState` is async. If you want to get the very last value of state you should use `this.setState`'s callback:

   ```
   this.setState({results:response}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.result); //<-- here you have the very last value of result
   });
   ```
2. state must be always setted with `this.setState`: `this.state.series.push(a.count)` is not good.

So you have to rewrite your code in this way:

```
        ...
        this.setState({results:response}, () => {
            let seriesAppo = [];
            this.state.results[0].map((a) => {
                seriesAppo.push(a.count);
            });
            this.setState({series: seriesAppo}, () => {
               console.log(this.state.series);
            })      
        });
        ...
```

Comment: may I know why there are empty array before the array with value?

Comment: @Unknown if you mean why state array is empty and after a while will be filled is because `GetTransaction` makes a fetch (so it takes time to response and in this time state is empty). Then fetch returns value and you call `setState` but also this is async and takes time to set state. Finally the state will be filled and you start to see correct values. Is just a matter of async calls that, as I told you, are taking time to be resolved. It's totally normal.

Comment: @Unknown No problem. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 1):

That‘s weird

```
   this.state.results[0].map((a) => {                
     this.state.series.push(a.count)
   });
```

Don‘t manipulate state that way, only with setState.

```
      const series = response[0];
      this.setState({series: series});
```

Even if you wanna add elements to an array you have to recreate the array. You can achieve this as follows:

```
     const series = response[0];
     this.setState({series: […this.state.series, …series]});
```